# Generate merged entity class files with symfony2

Tags: class, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm a little bit stuck with my poor knowledge of Symfony2 and Doctrine. Here is what I'm trying to do: I have two different files containing a class definition of the same class. I want to merge these two into a new class file.

I have an existing entity class file `Foo.php`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;  

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return void
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = (string) $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }   

    protected function someMagic($in) {
        die('no magic happens.');
    }
}
```

and a second entity class file with the same name Foo.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $color;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return void
     */
    public function setColor($color)
    {
        $this->color = $this->someColorMagic($color);
    }

    /**
     * @return string name
     */
    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }   

    protected function someMagic($in) {
        return 'magic: ' . $out;
    }
}
```

How can I merge these two together (not at runtime, just during installation of a symfony application - could be done with a symfony console command like `foobar:install`) so I get a merged class `Foo` written to a file `FooExtended.php` that contains properties and methods of both classes and the doctrine annotations preserved?

Does Symfony (or the DoctrineBundle within) support stuff like this out of the box? Or can someone point me into the right direction how this can be achieved?

Comment: what's wrong with copy/pasta? hard to answer this without knowing _why_ you'd want to do this. Can't the second class just extend the first one?

Comment: It should be generated programmatically during an installation. Extension is not an option here for several reasons (hard to explain in a nutshell).

Comment: PHP itself doesn't support multiple class inheritance so it's probably a no. Won't you need them to be one class on runtime as well anyway?

Comment: Yes, the class should always be generated as "Foo" afterwards. I found something like [Doctrator](https://github.com/pablodip/doctrator), but I'm not quite sure if this is what I need. But I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It now turned out with some changes in design I can solve my problem with simple class inheritance. So there is no need for a class merging at design time.